# Pyro4, serve object with constructor parameters. how?

Tags: python, pyro

I have an object that takes a parameter in the constructor. I was wondering how I can serve this from Pyro4. An Example:

```
import Pyro4

class MyPyroThing(object):
    def __init__(self, theNumber):
        self.Number = theNumber

Pyro4.Daemon.serveSimple(
    {
        MyPyroThing(): None
    },
    ns=True, verbose=True)
```

This **fails** of course because the constructor must have a parameter.

And when this is solved, how do you invoke such object?

```
theThing = Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:MyPyroThing")
```

**EDIT:**

I think this question was not written correctly, see my answer below.

Comment: If the question was not correctly asked as you say in your own answer, then please update the question so that it can be useful for other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers above where not what I was really asking, meaning I explained my question badly. Mea Culpa.

I wanted to invoke an instance on the client. But that is not how Pyro4 works at all. A class in instantiated on the server and this instance is transmitted over the wire.

After mailing [Irmin](http://www.razorvine.net/) (the original developer) it came clear to me how Pyro4 works.

So, what I do now is use a factory pattern where I ask the factory to give me an instance of an object. For instance:

```
psf = Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:MyApp.Factories.ProductFactory")
product = psf.GetProductOnButton(buttonNoPressed, parentProductId)
```

product is an instance of the Product() class. Because the instance is registered in the Pyro daemon, i can call methods on this instance of Product() too. Look at the shoppingcart example to know where I got my eureka moment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Pyro4.Daemon.serveSimple` you can:

- Get the name server using `Pyro4.locateNS`
- Create a `Pyro4.Daemon` object
- Create the objects you need to expose
- Use the daemon `register` method to make them available
- Use the name server `register` method to provide a name to uri mapping
- Start the daemon loop

The code would be more or less as follows:

```
import Pyro4

name_server = Pyro4.locateNS()
daemon = Pyro4.Daemon()
my_object = MyPyroThing(parameter)
my_object_uri = daemon.register(my_object)
name_server.register('MyPyroThing', my_object_uri)

daemon.requestLoop()
```

After this, `my_object` URI will be available in the name server as `MyPyroThing`.

Comment: And how would I invoke it from the client?

Comment: Given that the object has been registered in the name server with the name `MyPyroThing`, the code in the question should work, that is, `theThing = Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:MyPyroThing")`

Comment: Alternatively, you lookup the name in the name server and create a proxy for the returned URI (more efficient if you're going to send many messages to that object and it's not going to move to a different machine): `uri = name_server.lookup('MyPyroThing'); theThing = Pyro4.Proxy(uri)`