# Can't pass constructor parameters from client using pyro4

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpc, pyro4

This is my server.py:

```
import Pyro5.api

@Pyro5.api.expose
class GreetingMaker(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_fortune(self):
        return "Hello, {0}.".format(self.name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    daemon = Pyro5.api.Daemon()
    uri = daemon.register(GreetingMaker)
    print("Ready. Object uri =", uri)
    daemon.requestLoop()
```

Now my problem is, that I can't call the class using its constructor parameters. Is it possible what I'm trying to achieve?

Note: There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151108/pyro4-serve-object-with-constructor-parameters-how) in stackoverflow but I didn't find a straight forward answer from there about what I am looking for.